# How to use ts_query with ANY(anyarray)

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I currently have a query in PostgreSQL like:

```
SELECT
    name
FROM
    ingredients
WHERE
    name = ANY({"string value",tomato,other})
```

My ingredients table is simply a list of names:

```
   name
----------
 jalapeno
 tomatoes
 avocados
 lime
```

My issue is that plural values in the array will not match single values in the query. To solve this, I created a `tsvector` column on the table:

```
     name      |    tokens  
---------------+--------------
jalapeno       | 'jalapeno':1
tomatoes       | 'tomato':1
avocados       | 'avocado':1
lime           | 'lime':1
```

I'm able to correctly query single values from the table like this:

```
SELECT
    name,
    ts_rank_cd(tokens, plainto_tsquery('tomato'), 16) AS rank
FROM
    ingredients
WHERE
    tokens @@ plainto_tsquery('tomato')
ORDER BY
    rank DESC;
```

However, I need to query values from the entire array. The array is generated from another function, so I have control over the type of each of items in the array.

How can I use the `@@` operand with `ANY(anyarray)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be straight forward:

```
WHERE tokens @@ ANY
   (ARRAY[
      plainto_tsquery('tomato'),
      plainto_tsquery('celery'),
      plainto_tsquery('vodka')
   ])
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me pointed in the right direction. I actually had to `unwrap` the array and `JOIN` it as a table to use each item in the `ts_rank_cd` function too.